# Separar somente o email e usuário de uma string

Tags: php

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
$string = uniqid(mt_rand(1, 999999))." hello@world.com|example123456"
```

A string acima é totalmente aleatória, a única coisa que não muda é `hello@world.com|example123456`.

Quero que o PHP só retorne `hello@world.com|example123456`.

Procurei no Google pra ver se já tinha algum snippet ou exemplo, porem não encontrei nada.

Comment: $str = explode(" ", $string);  $userEmail = $str[1];

Comment: Qual a origem dessa string? Acredito que em algum momento você as tem separadamente!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = explode(" ", $string);

$userEmail = $str[1];  // hello@world.com|example123456

$partes = explode("|", $userEmail);

$email = $partes[0]; //hello@world.com

$user = $partes[1]; // example123456
```

Answer (score -2):

Use expressões regulares, em que linguagem precisa fazer? Provavelmente seria algo assim:

```
/w@/w|/w
```